# VBA ActiveCell set to Concatenated String

Tags: excel, vba

Long time reader first time asker..
I have been at wits end with setting an ActiveCell value to be a string type variable. I'm sure it is something simple however I just cannot figure out why the error is.. 
This code is running from my personal xlsb. 
Any help is appreciated and thank you in advanced.
 
 The error I get is runtime 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.  I am open to solutions, however I am more interested in why it doesn't work.

```
Public Sub gogogo()

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y, str1, str2, str3 As String

X = 1

Do

    Y = CStr(X)
    str1 = "=COUNTIF('Failure rate (Car)'!$B26:$BBB26,'="
    str2 = "')"
    str3 = str1 & Y & str2  'Successfully makes sentence'
    Cells(8, X + 14).Value = str3 'Dies on this line Error 1004'

    X = X + 1
    Loop Until X = 52

End Sub
```

Comment: To help you solve this by yourself, enter the formula manually in O8, then go to the Immediate window (ctrl+G in VBE) and type `? activecell.formula`

Comment: Thank you, it produces the formula as written """=COUNTIF('Failure rate (Car)'!$B50:$BBB50,"=1")""".
The only reason for this was to save a bit of time. It's costing alot more time than manually entering but I want to know why it's failing. I would normally just use the auto-fill but unfortunately it won't count up the Y inside the quotations.

Comment: You include Y in your formula by using `COLUMN()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for comments.

```
Dim X As Integer  
Dim Y, str1, str2, str3 As String
```

X should be a `Long`
Your second `Dim` defines Y, str1 and str2 as `Variant` and str3 as `String`.
Correct syntax would be:

```
Dim Y as string, str1 as string, str2 as string, str3 As String
```

For your formula, try

```
str3 = "=COUNTIF('Failure rate (Car)'!$B26:$BBB26, " & Y & ")"
```

And of course, like @Spencer Barnes mentioned, use `.Formula` instead of `.Value`

Comment: Thank you Patrick and Spencer, I am not eligible to cast a vote to say it was useful. I wasn't aware I could omit the "=1" for just a number. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

str3 is not  going to be the cell value, it's the cell formula:
`Cells(8, X + 14).Formula = str3`

If you want the cell to actually show the full 'sentence' rather than the result of the formula, put a single quote ' at the start (won't show in the cell).

Comment: Also, just using `Cells` will always refer to the active sheet - it's considered best practice to include a specific reference, either `For Each Cell in Range(...)` or `SheetVariable.Cells(...` to prevent it switching active sheet for any reason.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response, I've tried that however it seems I'm having the same error...